# VBA: Using ADODB Parameter

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I'm trying to run an parameterized SQL query with ADODB but I get the error message

> Must declade the scalar variable @Id

I'm a complete noob at VBA and I've tried reading up on how it's done as well as following an example but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong with my code?

```vb
Public Function IndataTest()    
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ConnString As String
    ConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=DB;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=B5037093;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DB"

    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim ParamId As Object
    Dim Id As String
    
    Id = 1084924
    
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "use DB " 
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "Select * " & vbCrLf
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "From tblA" & vbCrLf        
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "where fldA = @Id"
    
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open ConnString
    
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstr
    
    Set ParamId = cmd.CreateParameter("@Id", 129, 1, 52, Id)
    cmd.Parameters.Append ParamId
    
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open cmd
    
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets("Valuta").Cells(5, 5).CopyFromRecordset rs
        ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a parameter, build your value into your string

```
 Public Function IndataTest()


 Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
 Dim ConnString As String
 ConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=DB;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=B5037093;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DB"
  Dim sqlstr As String 
  Dim rs As new adodb.recordset
  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
  conn.Open ConnString

  sqlstr = "use DB " 
  sqlstr = sqlstr & "Select * " & vbCrLf 
  sqlstr = sqlstr & "From tblA" & vbCrLf 
  sqlstr = sqlstr & "where fldA = "  & 1084924
  set rs = conn.execute(sqlstr)
```

etc

Comment: This is the opposite of all other advice on the topic.

Comment: Parameters make sense if you are creating a public facing solution - but if you are creating an internal solution for selecting with a long (so no text symbols to mess up your sql) why bother doing the work?. Slavishly following "best practice" without understanding why it's best, just leads to unnecessary work.

Comment: ... why bother doing the work?....
Because in today's world anything you think is not 'public facing' can be reached by hackers.  Using Parameters is safer.  Old code, that should never have been "outside" the firewall is exploited by bad actors inside the firewall.

Comment: I know this comment is old but it's a really bad idea to construct the query like H.dad suggests. The SQL-server will calculate a new execution plan every time this query is run. The plan for a parameterized query is reused. It is most likely also saving a plan for each version of the query: new flda-value, new plan.
Then is the injection hacking issue. Maybe the query is copied to a place where it is vonourable to attacks. Maybe it is just exposed because of changes. It is always a bad a (and lazy) practice.

Answer (score -1):

The only place I know that named parameters works, is calling stored procedures (remember to set datatypes or all parameters become nvarchars; had a problem where a date (European: 11-01-2021 (11'th of January) became the 1'st of November).
Dealing with parameters for queries, use ? instead of a named parameter and run the query like rs = command.execute(parameters:=aKey). Accessing more than one parameter is something with a constructing a list of adodb.parameter and feed it to the parameters of the execute. Haven't had success with this yet, created a stored procedure.

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    '.NamedParameters = True
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[dbo].[LookupAValue]"
    .Parameters.Item("@registrered").Type = adDate
End With
```

Note that I set a parameter type to date. That is quite important. As I understand it it is also vital to access "sheet.cell(..,..).Value" instead "sheet.cell(..,..)". The first return the numerical value of the date where the latter return the visible value (a formatted date string). I may be wrong there, no expert in VBA.